# how can I add code that deletes a message when I react to a message? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a suggest command and I'm trying to make it so that when i react with emoji "x" message get's deleted. Can someone help me?

```
    owner.send(embed).then(m => {
        m.react("✅")
        m.react('❌')


    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen react change on message is sent you need to using `createReactionCollector()` [guide here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html)

This code is what you are looking for

Note: Your `exec` or `run` function must be async function

```js
const newMsg = await owner.send(embed);
await newMsg.react('❌');
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return user.id === msg.author.id; // Note msg is start commands message
};
let collector = await newMsg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                   time: 30000,
                });
collector.on('collect', async (r) => {
   if (r.emoji.name ==='❌') {
    collector.stop('delete');
    await newMsg.delete();
   }
});
```

Comment: tried the code however i got an error ReferenceError: filter is not defined

Comment: filter is to check who reaction :D I will give you example in edit

Comment: since I am using a command handler i switched msg with message and it worked! however i am receiving 2 messages from the bot, one which still does not get deleted the other does get deleted. do you know how to fix this issue? @HellCatVN

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem if my solution is worked! then you can mark it as solution and raise new issues describle